# Django current time zone remembered after logging out

Tags: django, timezone

After the user logs out, Django seems to remember the last activated timezone.

1. User posts form - datetime on form interpreted as UTC
2. User logs in with preferred timezone of Australia/Sydney
3. User posts form - datetime on form interpreted as Australia/Sydney
4. User logs out
5. User posts form - datetime on form still interpreted as Australia Sydney, even though TIME_ZONE is set to UTC
6. Restarting the server, and then user (still not logged in) posts form - datetime on form interpreted as UTC

I have

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_TZ = True
```

and as middleware:

```
class TimezoneMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):

        tz = request.session.get('django_timezone', '')
        if tz:
            timezone.activate(tz)
        elif request.user.is_authenticated():
            preferredTimezone = request.user.get_profile().preferredTimezone
            timezone.activate(preferredTimezone)
```

I think that Django might be remembering the last previously activated timezone, as indicated in this comment for the `activate` function in the source:

```
def activate(timezone):
    """
    Sets the time zone for the current thread.

    The ``timezone`` argument must be an instance of a tzinfo subclass or a
    time zone name. If it is a time zone name, pytz is required.
    """
    if isinstance(timezone, tzinfo):
        _active.value = timezone
```

Can someone confirm this? Would the best way of solving this would be to, in the middleware, have an else statement that calls `deactivate`?

Answer (score 2):

First, session != authentication.

Probably in between steps 2 and 4 (when the user is logged in), one of your views (or some kind of middleware) sets the user's session with `request.session['django_timezone'] = ...`

Maybe you transfer profile information to the session somewhere with something like:

```
request.session['django_timezone']  = request.user.get_profile().prefferedTimezone
```

Then, it's natural that even if the user logs out, the session keeps 'django_timezone'.

If you don't want to take advantage of that, do rather, in the first place:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    timezone.deactivate()
```

But the real question you should ask yourself I think is:
*Why use request.session if you don't want to use sessions, and rather purely the profile?*